# DatabaseError at /admin/blogengine/post/add/

Tags: database, django-admin

Newbie here. I'm trying to create a blog using Django. Before I added a slug to the posts, everything worked/posted fine. However, since I add the slug, I get error messages when I try to add a post saying DatabaseError at /admin/blogengine/post/add/
no such column: blogengine_post.slug. The error traceback is:

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blogengine',
 'django.contrib.admin')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /Users/chrissiepollock/projects/DjangoBlog/templates/posts.html, error at line 6
   no such column: blogengine_post.slug
   1 : <html>


   2 :     <head>


   3 :         <title>My Django Blog</title>


   4 :     </head>


   5 :     <body>


   6 :          {% for post in posts %} 


   7 :         <h1><a href="/{{ post.slug }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>


   8 :         <h3>{{ post.pub_date }}</h3>


   9 :         {{ post.text }}


   10 :         {% endfor %}


   11 :         <br />


   12 :         {% if page.has_previous %}


   13 :         <a href="/{{ page.previous_page_number }}/">Previous Page</a>


   14 :         {% endif %}


   15 :         {% if page.has_next %}


   16 :         <a href="/{{ page.next_page_number }}/">Next Page</a>


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/chrissiepollock/projects/DjangoBlog/blogengine/views.py" in getPost
  27.     return render_to_response('posts.html', { 'posts':post})
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
  29.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  172.         return t.render(Context(dictionary))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  148.         len_values = len(values)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  90.                 self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  301.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in results_iter
  775.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  840.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  41.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  366.             six.reraise(utils.DatabaseError, utils.DatabaseError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  362.             return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: DatabaseError at /admin
Exception Value: no such column: blogengine_post.slug
```

I ran manage.py sqlall myapp and according to it, the slug info is there(unless I'm reading something wrong):

```
CREATE TABLE "blogengine_post" (
"id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"title" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
"pub_date" datetime NOT NULL,
"text" text NOT NULL,
"slug" varchar(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE
```

)
;

I've been trying to figure this out for days, doing line-by-line read-throughs, starting from scratch and relocating files and folders, but nothing works. Any ideas? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution according to Matthew Daly:

The problem is that running syncdb can create new tables, but cannot amend existing ones. As a result, the slug column isn't added.

The simplest solution is to just delete backend.db and run python manage.py syncdb again to rebuild it using the new schema.

A more sophisticated solution is to use South to create and manage database migrations. With South, you can easily migrate databases to a new structure, or roll them back. It's out of scope for this tutorial, but I would recommend having at look at http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/02/09/starting-a-django-project-the-right-way/ to give you a good idea of how to start using South.

Answer (score 0):

Syncdb don't change the existing schema it just looks for new table schema which are not present and create them.
I will suggest using of [South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to keep track of all the database changes, it is very useful. One more thing to note, if your any app is under south inspection then your new tables also will be created with south migrations(syncdb won't work for those apps)

For Ex:

```
./manage.py convert_to_south appname
```

Do changes then

```
  ./manage.py schemamigration --auto app_name
./manage.py migrate app_name
```

For more help you can check here:

[South Help](https://gist.github.com/DaveEveritt/453421)